# ADB over TCP - Devices are connected and online but installing shows Error: Device not found

Tags: android, adb

Good day,

I've been using a VMWare android machine and installing .apks on it but after my computer was unexpectedly shut down and tried to re-install a package I've been having the following problem:

```
$ adb -s 192.168.1.2 install 'myapp.apk'
error: device not found
- waiting for device -
```

However I was able to connect the VM using adb connect 192.168.1.2 which is the ip currently assigned on the android, (seen it on ctrl+f1 netcfg) and then shows:

```
connected to 192.168.1.2:5555

$ adb devices
List of devices attached 
emulator-5554   offline
192.168.1.2:5555    device
```

so it appears to be online.

Troubleshooting steps taken before posting:

- $adb kill/start-server
- Reconfigured the VM Network (I have it bridged and Internet connection works fine).
  -Suspending/Shutting down and Restarting VM.
  -Restarting Internet connection (Router/PC connections)

Kindly assist with situation or post links of another issue related to mine that I probably did not find (sorry for that..)

Thanks!

Edit: I'm using Fedora as OS, Eclipse for developing

Comment: how did you get `192.168.1.2:5555`? did you run tcp connect to that IP before?

Comment: yes, it is actualy the ip assigned to the android machine according to netcfg, it shows this **eth0 UP 192.168.1.2 255.255.255.0 0X00001043**

Comment: before no, before it was this one, **192.168.251.128**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When using an ADB tcp target, the device name specified in the -s parameter must include not only the IP address but the port as well, for example:

```
adb -s 192.168.1.2:5555 install 'myapp.apk'
```

(As the android emulator actually talks over TCP behind it's "emulator-####" name, one can test this by connecting to an emulator at the loopback address using the control port plus one, ie, "emulator-5554" can also be reached as a vanilla tcp target via `adb connect 127.0.0.1:5555` and then you can install on it with `adb -s 127:0.0.1:5555 install whatever`)